# Offline messages not being send to adafruit iot portal by mosquitto broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I have a raspberry pi in which I have installed mosquitto broker and mqtt. Pi is connected to sensor and  I need to send this data to `adafruit IOT protal`. I am able to send all the data when the pi is connected but when the pi goes offline, I am only able to transmit data for 20-30 sec. If the pi is offline for more than 2-3 mins then that data is not transmitted to portal.

I have created a bridge.conf file and add all the configurations to be used my mosquitto. Here is the content:

```
connection iothub
address io.adafruit.com:1883
remote_username <username>
remote_password <password>
remote_clientid sensor1
bridge_cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
try_private false
cleansession false
start_type automatic
bridge_insecure false
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
bridge_tls_version tlsv1
notifications false
max_queued_messages 0
autosave_interval 5

topic # out 2 /sensors/sensor1
topic # in 2 /sensors/sensor1
```

I have set the cleansession false and using QOS 2. I have also set max_queued_messages to 0 which means maximum. The problem I am facing is if the pi if offline for just 1-2min, I am able to get all the offline data but if it is offline for more than 3-4 mins, I don't receive any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of persisting mechanism do you have on the sensor side in the case your pi goes offline?

As far as i could remember, mqtt by default stores only a short amount of data on the client side if the broker goes offline.

In fact, i think it stores data as long as the client still tries to send data to the broker. In other words, as long as it does not hit the timeout. I think this is 15sec by default.

**EDIT**

If you want to increase this timeout, you have to increase the `keep-alive` time. With the Paho Python library it looks like this.

```
client.connect(host="localhost", port=1883, keepalive=60)
```

Keep in mind, that the max. keepalive time is 18h 12min 15 sec.

From the [OASIS documentation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/csprd01/mqtt-v3.1.1-csprd01.html)

> The Keep Alive is a time interval measured in seconds. Expressed as a
>   16-bit word, it is the maximum time interval that is permitted to
>   elapse between two successive Control Packets sent by the Client.

When you calculate the 65535s (maximum for the 16bit word) to a more readable format, you will get 18h 12min 15 sec.

Comment: On the raspberry pi side, I have a python code which keeps on publishing the data in a loop with 5 sec delay. So I am sure that code will always send the data and even I can also see it from the logs. The `15sec` default which you are saying, can we increase it.?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Ok so if I set keep alive to 60, it will hit the timeout after 60sec so after this 60 sec it might not queue the data, hence the data will be lost.? Am I right.?

Comment: Where did you find that the max limit of keep alive time is 18h 12min 15sec.? Please add a link to it

Comment: Updated with a link

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be working although I have not tested it for long period of time. But one thing I found a bit strange is that the size of the mosquitto.db file remains the same. It doesnt increase, which I think should increase. Do you have any idea about this.?

Comment: Oh. I think that the mosquitto.db file is just used for persisting msg that are in in flight. That they are not lost while the ack process is going on. But it is a long time since i last used mosquitto

Comment: I set the keepalive to 1hr but it is only saving the data for like 15mins only. If the device if offline for more than 15mins, no data is received and the messages are ignored.